# Multiple Logins for one market.android.com/publish Account

Tags: android

Is there a way to create multiple logins for one market.android.com/publish Account?

There must be role separation included.

We need one for developers who do not have access to corporate checking account information.

Regards,
Charles

Comment: It is essentially just a standard google account for the market publish. As far as I know google doesn't offer that sort of account breakdown for any of their services, including the Market publish.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to currently do this.  It's pretty frustrating for us as well (and I'm sure a lot of people).  According to a few google groups posts I've seen Google says "they'll keep it in mind"...so who knows when they'll actually do it.

https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/android-market/y0s7zYUWlq8